# iptables nat FTP

Tags: ftp, iptables, nat

I have computer (ubuntu server). Server have internet and share internet for local network. There is one computer in local network have FTP. How to get access to local FTP from internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good Site to take a look: [Linux Firewalls using iptables](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_%3a_Ch14_%3a_Linux_Firewalls_Using_iptables)

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i ppp0 --dport 21 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.1:21
```

ppp0 = Interface WWW

192.168.1.1 = The Server which provides FTP in your Lan